# Замена параметра LINQ на переменную

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, linq

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как  можно считать число из input и передать в сортируемый параметр LINQ через переменную (вместо числа 2017)? Если считываю через js не получается записать значение input в переменную c#[image: стрелкой указано число которое требуется передавать сюда из input]

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста ваш код текстом, чтобы отвечающему для сборки примера не пришлось перепечатывать ваш код с картинки.

Comment: Если вы читаете ввод js-ом , то вызывайте post запрос с передачей введенных данных, а уже в контроллере или резор странице получайте в методе обрабатывающем этот post запрос через параметр данные введенные пользователем. а далее как обычно.